# Closing an expanded menu in qt

Tags: c++, qt5

I have a menu and it has a number of menu items. Usually when menu is clicked it expands. But in some situations when the menu is clicked its action need to be fired but menu should not be expanded. How can we do this in qt?

Comment: Does `void QMenu::setDefaultAction(QAction *act)` do what you want?